# Capture the number of tables JOINED in SQL in Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, newrelic

I have a Rails app. In many cases the SQL is generated dynamically. In these queries it creates JOINs with multiple tables. I want to capture the no of joins(no of tables joined) and trigger a custom event/report on newrelic. Basically, the moment the no of tables JOINEDed increases by x, it should send an event to new relic

Comment: well if you generate the sql dynamically, you can count how many tables are involve and include one aditional field. What is the problem? How are you creating the query?

Comment: The SQl is generated with mix of some dynamic looping, with addition of scopes. A similar scenario is at multiple places.

Comment: So what is the problem of couting inside the loop?